# Error in parsing xml from web service

Tags: android, saxparser

I have my xml file as a response in `result.getProperty(0)`.

The code is as follows:

```
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;    
System.out.println("value of result " + result);
```

How can I store this xml in `result.getProperty(0)` into my sdcard/any other location so that I can parse it using SAXParser?

Regards,
sneha

Comment: If you receive xml file as response,it is easy to parse using SAX or DOM...but if you receive soap object as response you should manually parse yourself. if you could post ur response we can able to solve it.

Comment: My XML response is this:: <ns:function1Response xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/axis2"> <ns:return>                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> <Discount>                                                          <shop_id>1</shop_id>                     <product_id>11</product_id> <product_name>Soap</product_name>   <shop_id>1</shop_id><product_id>12</product_id><product_name>Trousers</product_name></Discount></ns:return> </ns:function1Response>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in the following way :

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getProperty(0).toString().getBytes())));
```

Then I use SAXParser and parse the xml.

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

The `getProperty(int)`-method returns an Object. If this Object is a String, the SAXParser supports parsing XML from a String: [Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler%29)

Comment: But when i try to do the following it's throwing some serializable exception :                                                          File demofile = new File(root,"myxml.xml");
   
   //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(demofile);
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(demofile);
   
   //ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
   ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

   
   //String today = (String) ois.readObject();
    oos.writeObject(result.getProperty(0));

   oos.close();  I have implemented serializable too.  but it did not work

Comment: please edit your original post and past the code there, i can't read it like this.